# r - Length and sum of runs of negative values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains around 200 columns representing monthly drought measurements from 1999 to 2015. The values in each column can either be positive or negative. Each row in the dataframe represents a focal year that I'm interested in calculating metrics in reference to. The focal year is represented in another column. There can be multiple rows with the same focal year if they represent measurements from different sites (FIPS column). Here's a toy version (updated version!) of the dataframe:

```
    structure(list(FIPS = c(19045, 48157, 20045, 20027), Year = c(2003, 
2004, 2005, 2005), pdsi_2002.01.15 = c(1.46, 4.38, 0.38, -1.41
), pdsi_2002.02.15 = c(1.6, 3.63, -0.05, -1.66), pdsi_2002.03.15 = c(1.32, 
3, -0.62, -1.93), pdsi_2002.04.15 = c(1.81, 2.68, 0.66, -1.88
), pdsi_2002.05.15 = c(2.03, 1.86, 1.26, -1.7), pdsi_2002.06.15 = c(2.51, 
1.74, -0.5, -2.94), pdsi_2002.07.15 = c(2.79, 1.94, -1.47, -3.82
), pdsi_2002.08.15 = c(3.06, 2.64, -1.99, -4.09), pdsi_2002.09.15 = c(2.08, 
3.02, -2.82, -4.87), pdsi_2002.10.15 = c(2.68, 4.73, -2.02, -3.01
), pdsi_2002.11.15 = c(2, 5.28, -2.55, -3.22), pdsi_2002.12.15 = c(1.55, 
5.94, -3.23, -3.52), pdsi_2003.01.15 = c(0.96, 5.39, -3.58, -3.51
), pdsi_2003.02.15 = c(0.29, 5.24, -3.54, -3.29), pdsi_2003.03.15 = c(-0.15, 
4.41, -3.77, -3.15), pdsi_2003.04.15 = c(-1.13, 3.39, -3.33, 
-2.46), pdsi_2003.05.15 = c(-1.05, 1.91, -3.47, -2.63), pdsi_2003.06.15 = c(-1.5, 
1.45, -2.94, -2.34), pdsi_2003.07.15 = c(-0.85, 1.69, -3.42, 
-3.02), pdsi_2003.08.15 = c(-1.78, 1.48, -2.75, -3.13), pdsi_2003.09.15 = c(-1.55, 
2.31, -2.66, -2.85), pdsi_2003.10.15 = c(-1.87, 2.5, -2.99, -3.16
), pdsi_2003.11.15 = c(-1.19, 2.72, -3.39, -2.73), pdsi_2003.12.15 = c(0.09, 
2.67, -2.96, -2.63), pdsi_2004.01.15 = c(-0.2, 3.2, -2.83, -2.42
), pdsi_2004.02.15 = c(0.07, 3.73, -2.78, -2.21), pdsi_2004.03.15 = c(1.58, 
3.04, -1.66, -0.77), pdsi_2004.04.15 = c(0.37, 3.19, -2, -1.25
), pdsi_2004.05.15 = c(1.7, 3.71, -1.35, -1.41), pdsi_2004.06.15 = c(1.53, 
5.21, -0.84, -1.04), pdsi_2004.07.15 = c(1.14, 4.84, 2.08, 0.93
), pdsi_2004.08.15 = c(1.4, 4.41, 3.22, 0.24), pdsi_2004.09.15 = c(-0.43, 
3.27, 2.39, -0.44), pdsi_2004.10.15 = c(0.77, 2.77, 2.49, -1.11
), pdsi_2004.11.15 = c(0.94, 4.95, 2.94, -1.03), pdsi_2004.12.15 = c(0.62, 
4.41, 2.67, -1.43), pdsi_2005.01.15 = c(1.51, 3.93, 3.55, -1.05
), pdsi_2005.02.15 = c(1.45, 4.54, 3.83, 0.71), pdsi_2005.03.15 = c(0.58, 
4.31, 3.01, 0.24), pdsi_2005.04.15 = c(-0.97, 3.36, 1.97, 0.94
), pdsi_2005.05.15 = c(-1.57, 3.12, 1.54, -0.33), pdsi_2005.06.15 = c(-2.65, 
2.02, 2.33, 1.16), pdsi_2005.07.15 = c(-3.58, 2.07, 2.31, 1.08
), pdsi_2005.08.15 = c(-3.51, 1.56, 3.7, 1.72), pdsi_2005.09.15 = c(-3.96, 
-0.71, 3.62, 0.74), pdsi_2005.10.15 = c(-4.77, -2.13, 3.79, 0.96
), pdsi_2005.11.15 = c(-5.08, -2.32, 3.4, 0.53), pdsi_2005.12.15 = c(-5.63, 
-2.57, 3.27, -0.22)), .Names = c("FIPS", "Year", "pdsi_2002.01.15", 
"pdsi_2002.02.15", "pdsi_2002.03.15", "pdsi_2002.04.15", "pdsi_2002.05.15", 
"pdsi_2002.06.15", "pdsi_2002.07.15", "pdsi_2002.08.15", "pdsi_2002.09.15", 
"pdsi_2002.10.15", "pdsi_2002.11.15", "pdsi_2002.12.15", "pdsi_2003.01.15", 
"pdsi_2003.02.15", "pdsi_2003.03.15", "pdsi_2003.04.15", "pdsi_2003.05.15", 
"pdsi_2003.06.15", "pdsi_2003.07.15", "pdsi_2003.08.15", "pdsi_2003.09.15", 
"pdsi_2003.10.15", "pdsi_2003.11.15", "pdsi_2003.12.15", "pdsi_2004.01.15", 
"pdsi_2004.02.15", "pdsi_2004.03.15", "pdsi_2004.04.15", "pdsi_2004.05.15", 
"pdsi_2004.06.15", "pdsi_2004.07.15", "pdsi_2004.08.15", "pdsi_2004.09.15", 
"pdsi_2004.10.15", "pdsi_2004.11.15", "pdsi_2004.12.15", "pdsi_2005.01.15", 
"pdsi_2005.02.15", "pdsi_2005.03.15", "pdsi_2005.04.15", "pdsi_2005.05.15", 
"pdsi_2005.06.15", "pdsi_2005.07.15", "pdsi_2005.08.15", "pdsi_2005.09.15", 
"pdsi_2005.10.15", "pdsi_2005.11.15", "pdsi_2005.12.15"), row.names = c(13222L, 
18125L, 19543L, 19534L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I'd like to do is calculate the length and sum of each run of negative values in the focal year (so looking for runs in the same row, across columns), then calculate the mean run length, mean run sum, and mean of each run sum divided by each run length for each row. Adding another layer of difficulty, if the January measurement in the focal year is negative, I'd like to then look back to the years before the focal year to account for a situation where the run of negative numbers started in a previous year. The run could conceivably extend all the way to January 1999.

I've been able to calculate the run length metric using rle(), but haven't been able to figure out how to get run sums.

Comment: What is your expected result for the toy example? On line 5, you have two runs with negative numbers. How do you want to have that in a table?

Comment: I was envisioning having three columns added to the dataframe, one for each of the requested metrics. For example, in row 5 of the toy example, the value in the first added column representing mean run length would be (2 +1)/2= 1.5, the value in the second new column for mean run sum would be (-6 + -2)/2= -4, and the last column value would be -4/1.5= 2.66.

Comment: actually the last value above should be ((-6/2) + (-2/1)) / 2 = -2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may work for what you are looking for, this will generate the 3 required values, for the year specified, and if there is a negative value in January it will continue that run down until a positive value is reached in the previous year.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

select.order <- colnames(drought_data)[3:length(colnames(drought_data))]

drought_data <- drought_data %>% 
                # Gather data by date
                gather(key = date, value = value, -Year, -FIPS) %>% 
                # Separate date into separate columns
                separate(date, into = c("yr","month", "day"), sep = "\\.") %>% 
                # Extract year
                mutate(yr = substr(yr, 6, 9)) %>%
                # Sort data by FIPS number, year, month
                arrange(FIPS, yr, month) %>%
                # Group data by FIPS number, focal year, and data year
                group_by(FIPS, Year, yr) %>%
                # Generate a run number for each run of negative numbers for the focal year
                mutate(run.num = ifelse(Year == yr,
                                 {run.num = rle(ifelse(value < 0, 1, 0)) 
                                  rep(ifelse(run.num$values == 1, cumsum(run.num$values), 0), run.num$lengths)}, NA),
                       # Set run.num to -1 for positive values
                       run.num = ifelse(value >= 0, -1, run.num)) %>%
                # Sort data by FIPS number, descending year, and descending month
                arrange(FIPS, desc(yr), desc(month)) %>%
                # Group data by FIPS number and focal year
                group_by(FIPS, Year) %>%
                # Fill out the run numbers for each run to cross data years
                fill(run.num, .direction = "down") %>%
                # Convert all -1 run numbers (Which indicate positive values) to zero
                mutate(run.num = ifelse(run.num == -1, 0, run.num),
                       # Set run.num for negative values that did not qualify as a run for the specified year to 0
                       run.num = ifelse(is.na(run.num), 0, run.num)) %>%
                ungroup %>%
                # mutate(run.num = ifelse(is.na(run.num, 0, run.num))) %>%
                # Group data by FIPS number, focal year, and run number
                group_by(FIPS, Year, run.num) %>%
                # Calculate the length, sum, and rate of each run
                mutate(run.length = ifelse(run.num == 0, 0, n()),
                       run.sum = ifelse(run.num == 0, 0, sum(value)),
                       run.rate = ifelse(run.num == 0, 0, run.sum/run.length)) %>%
                # Group by FIPS number and focal year
                group_by(FIPS, Year) %>%
                # Calculate the mean run length, and mean run sum for the focal year of each FIPS number
                mutate(mean.run.length = sum(ifelse(run.num == 0, 0, 1)) / max(run.num),
                       mean.run.length = ifelse(is.nan(mean.run.length), 0, mean.run.length),
                       mean.run.sum = sum(ifelse(run.num == 0, 0, value) / max(run.num)),
                       mean.run.sum = ifelse(is.nan(mean.run.sum), 0, mean.run.sum)) %>%
                # Combine date parts back to single column
                unite(dt, yr:day, sep = ".") %>% 
                # Recreate the pdsi_ label format on the date column
                mutate(dt = paste0("pdsi_", dt)) %>%
                # Drop the run.sum column
                select(-run.sum) %>% 
                # Spread the data back to a wide view to eliminate duplicate run.rate values
                spread(dt, value) %>% 
                # Group data by FIPS number and focal year
                group_by(FIPS, Year) %>% 
                # Calculate the mean of the sum of run rates over the number of runs
                mutate(mean.run.sum.length = sum(run.rate) / max(run.num),
                       mean.run.sum.length = ifelse(is.nan(mean.run.sum.length), 0, mean.run.sum.length)) %>% 
                # Remove grouping
                ungroup %>% 
                # Drop the run.num, run.length, and run.rate columns 
                select(-run.num, -run.length, -run.rate) %>% 
                # Gather the data into tall view to remove duplicates and NA values
                gather_("dt", "value", select.order, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
                # Spread data back to wide view
                spread(dt, value)

# Change the column order
drought_data <- drought_data[,c("FIPS","Year","mean.run.length","mean.run.sum","mean.run.sum.length", select.order)]
```

The final output will be the original dataframe with the three additional calculated columns included. Below is the output of the calculated columns for the provided test dataset.

```
> drought_data[,c("FIPS","Year","mean.run.length","mean.run.sum","mean.run.sum.length")]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   FIPS  Year mean.run.length mean.run.sum mean.run.sum.length
  <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>        <dbl>               <dbl>
1 19045  2003        9.000000       -11.07          -1.2300000
2 20027  2005        2.333333        -1.87          -0.5206667
3 20045  2005        0.000000         0.00           0.0000000
4 48157  2004        0.000000         0.00           0.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you, this is excellent and does exactly what I want! I did run into one problem. For some reason the n() does not seem to be working within run.length =ifelse(run.num == 0, 0, n()). I'm wondering if it's a bug. Anyway, I got around the problem by doing run.length = n(), then retroactively changing all the positive run lengths back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach to the problem, at least the first part. But I believe that it also gets at the second part of your problem.

In my view, it is helpful to bring the data in a different, tidy format where each row is an monthly observation in a separate focal year. (Btw, I wasn't sure why the `focal_ years` column was all `2001`. Per your data description, shouldn't it be separate years?)

```
library(tidyverse)

drought_data_tidy <- drought_data %>% 
  gather(key, value, -FIPS, -Year) %>% 
  arrange(FIPS)
```

This gives us the following data structure (note that I added a row id, since the focal year is always the same. If that's a mistake on your part, the code simplifies somewhat):

```
> head(drought_data_tidy)
  FIPS Year             key value
1 8019 2005 pdsi_2002.01.15 -1.73
2 8019 2005 pdsi_2002.02.15 -2.04
3 8019 2005 pdsi_2002.03.15 -2.44
4 8019 2005 pdsi_2002.04.15 -3.55
5 8019 2005 pdsi_2002.05.15 -3.84
6 8019 2005 pdsi_2002.06.15 -4.42
```

The only "difficulty" is to create a unique `run_id` for each negative run which we get this way:

```
drought_data_tidy <- drought_data_tidy %>% 
  group_by(FIPS) %>% 
  mutate(run_id = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(value < 0) != 0)), 
         run_id = ifelse(value < 0, run_id, NA))
```

Now all that remains is the appropriate `group_by` and `mean` commands. Note that I select the relevant parts of the values on which we do the calculations through `[!is.na(run_id)]`; we could also create another grouping variable for this which might be more elegant.

Given your updated data and the problems with `unique()` I decided to put the calculations through `summarize()` commands and store the results in separate data frames that I join in back in end. It's also possible to do it in one giant dplyr chain, but I think this approach is somewhat easier to read and better for bug fixing.

```
# run length
drought_data_run_length <- drought_data_tidy %>% 
  group_by(FIPS, run_id) %>% 
  summarize(run_length = n()) %>%  
  mutate(mean_run_length = mean(run_length[!is.na(run_id)]))

# mean run length for join
drought_data_mean_run_length <- drought_data_run_length %>% 
  group_by(FIPS) %>% 
  summarise(mean_run_length = unique(mean_run_length))

# run sum
drought_data_tidy <- drought_data_tidy %>% 
  group_by(FIPS, run_id) %>% 
  mutate(run_sum = sum(value))

# mean run sum
drought_data_mean_run_sum <- drought_data_tidy %>% 
  group_by(FIPS) %>%
  summarise(mean_run_sum = mean(run_sum[!is.na(run_id)]))

# mean run sum by mean run length
drought_data_mrs_by_mrl <- left_join(drought_data_mean_run_sum, 
                                     drought_data_mean_run_length,
                                     by = "FIPS") %>% 
  mutate(mrs_by_mrl = mean(mean_run_sum / mean_run_length))

# join run length, mean run length, mean run sum, mrs_by_mrl

drought_data_tidy <- left_join(drought_data_tidy, 
                               drought_data_run_length %>% select(-mean_run_length), 
                               by = c("FIPS", "run_id"))

drought_data_tidy <- left_join(drought_data_tidy, 
                               drought_data_mean_run_length %>% select(FIPS, mean_run_length), 
                               by = "FIPS")

drought_data_tidy <- left_join(drought_data_tidy, 
                               drought_data_mean_run_sum %>% select(FIPS, mean_run_sum), 
                               by = "FIPS")

drought_data_tidy <- left_join(drought_data_tidy, 
                               drought_data_mrs_by_mrl %>% select(FIPS, mrs_by_mrl), 
                               by = "FIPS")
```

This gives you the following output:

```
> head(drought_data_tidy)
Source: local data frame [6 x 10]
Groups: FIPS, run_id [1]

   FIPS  Year             key value run_id run_sum run_length mean_run_length mean_run_sum mrs_by_mrl
  <dbl> <dbl>           <chr> <dbl>  <int>   <dbl>      <int>           <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>
1  8019  2005 pdsi_2002.01.15 -1.73      1  -49.33         14               9    -33.54481  -3.542602
2  8019  2005 pdsi_2002.02.15 -2.04      1  -49.33         14               9    -33.54481  -3.542602
3  8019  2005 pdsi_2002.03.15 -2.44      1  -49.33         14               9    -33.54481  -3.542602
4  8019  2005 pdsi_2002.04.15 -3.55      1  -49.33         14               9    -33.54481  -3.542602
5  8019  2005 pdsi_2002.05.15 -3.84      1  -49.33         14               9    -33.54481  -3.542602
6  8019  2005 pdsi_2002.06.15 -4.42      1  -49.33         14               9    -33.54481  -3.542602
```

Now you can easily spread this back to the original data format. However, I believe that the `tidy` data frame of the monthly observations in a long format are more useful to get at the second part of your question with some clever use of `first()`. But to solve this we would need a bit more of your data (or toy data) that extends to different `focal_years`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks for the help! This has definitely gotten me on the right track. Unfortunately, I don't think the method above is properly accounting for run length. Runs were calculated as being far longer than is correct, but I wasn't able to determine the reason for this. Another potential issue is that using the unique() function on the run_length and row_sum columns may end up incorrectly grouping different runs if they happen to be of the same length or have the same sum. I uploaded a more realistic subset of the data in case this helps you or someone else who works on this problem.

Comment: you're right, `unique()` might cause problems down the line. I've updated my answer accordingly (the updated data was useful). I've slightly changed the approach to several `summarize()` statements on the grouping FIPS variable. Let me know if this is useful

Comment: Yes this is useful, thanks again for all your help. Right now, this is calculating values for all negative runs in a row (i.e. across all the years). For example, the row with Year=2004 and FIPS=48157 has no runs in the focal year, but still produces a value for run length/run sum. Ideally, it would include only runs in the focal year (Year column) and would produce a zero in the above example, which is fairly easy to fix if I extract dates from the column names. The tricky part will be to look back to the years before the focal year if a run in the focal year started in a previous year.

Comment: ok, thanks for the feedback. It seems that I still don't fully understand your data structure. In the example you give, the row with FIPS = 48517 & Year 2004 has a negative run from `pdsi_2005.09.15` onwards. Now, that month itself is not in the focal year (if 2004 itself is the focal year), but it is still in the *row* of the focal year. Is this correct? If so, yeah, then you'd simply only include the pdsi months in the calculation that are of the same year. If you need guidance on that let me know, but it shouldnt be too problematic.

Comment: The tricky part is indeed the "looking back". Could you edit your question with an example of how you would like the output for this to look like? This would help, since the data structure is somewhat complicated...